# partitioning: views versus tables with inheritance - what's the point?

Tags: performance, postgresql

My fundamental question is whether the parent table for tables with inheritance is the same thing / performs similarly to a view, and if so (which appears to be the case), why not use the view.

To investigate this, I decided to try to evaluate differences in performance between a single table, a view based on monthly tables, and monthly tables with inheritance. This gets pretty long, so feel free to make suggestions on perhaps appending code outside of stackoverflow, if that is preferred, or other ways I can simplify this. I will be describing what I am doing as well, so you don't necessarily need to run the code.

I wanted 200 entities with 50 values for each each minute of 2012. First, I made my big table "public.test_wide_no_inheritance" and each of the smaller monthly tables "public.test_wide_inheritance_YYYYMM" with inheritance to an empty table like the former "public.test_wide_inheritance", and finally a view based on the smaller tables,"test_wide_inheritance_2012":

```
create table public.test_wide_no_inheritance
as
select *
from(
SELECT entity, localt, 
random()as val01,random()as val02,random()as val03,random()as val04,random()as val05,random()as val06,random()as val07,random()as val08,random()as val09,random()as val10,
random()as val11,random()as val12,random()as val13,random()as val14,random()as val15,random()as val16,random()as val17,random()as val18,random()as val19,random()as val20,
random()as val21,random()as val22,random()as val23,random()as val24,random()as val25,random()as val26,random()as val27,random()as val28,random()as val29,random()as val30,
random()as val31,random()as val32,random()as val33,random()as val34,random()as val35,random()as val36,random()as val37,random()as val38,random()as val39,random()as val40,
random()as val41,random()as val42,random()as val43,random()as val44,random()as val45,random()as val46,random()as val47,random()as val48,random()as val49,random()as val50
FROM generate_series('2012-01-01'::timestamp, '2012-12-31'::timestamp, interval '1 minutes') as localt
join 
(select *
FROM generate_series(1, 200, 1) as entity) as entity
on 1=1) as data;

CREATE INDEX ix_public_test_wide_no_inheritance_entity
  ON public.test_wide_no_inheritance (entity);

CREATE INDEX ix_public_test_wide_no_inheritance_localt
  ON public.test_wide_no_inheritance (localt);

create table public.test_wide_inheritance (like public.test_wide); 

CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201201 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-01-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-02-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201202 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-02-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-03-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201203 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-03-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-04-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201204 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-04-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-05-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201205 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-05-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-06-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201206 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-06-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-07-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201207 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-07-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-08-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201208 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-08-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-09-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201209 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-09-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-10-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201210 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-10-01' AND localt < DATE '2012-11-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201211 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-11-01' AND localt < DATE '2013-01-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE TABLE public.test_wide_inheritance_201212 (
    CHECK ( localt >= DATE '2012-12-01' AND localt < DATE '2013-01-01' )
) INHERITS (public.test_wide_inheritance);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201201_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201201 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201202_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201202 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201203_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201203 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201204_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201204 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201205_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201205 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201206_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201206 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201207_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201207 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201208_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201208 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201209_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201209 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201210_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201210 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201211_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201211 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201212_localt ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201212 (localt);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201201_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201201 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201202_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201202 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201203_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201203 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201204_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201204 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201205_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201205 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201206_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201206 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201207_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201207 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201208_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201208 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201209_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201209 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201210_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201210 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201211_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201211 (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_wide_inheritance_201212_entity ON public.test_wide_inheritance_201212 (entity);

insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201201 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-01-01' AND localt < '2012-02-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201202 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-02-01' AND localt < '2012-03-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201203 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-03-01' AND localt < '2012-04-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201204 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-04-01' AND localt < '2012-05-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201205 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-05-01' AND localt < '2012-06-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201206 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-06-01' AND localt < '2012-07-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201207 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-07-01' AND localt < '2012-08-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201208 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-08-01' AND localt < '2012-09-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201209 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-09-01' AND localt < '2012-10-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201210 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-10-01' AND localt < '2012-11-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201211 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-11-01' AND localt < '2012-12-01';
insert into public.test_wide_inheritance_201212 select * from public.test_wide_no_inheritance where localt >= '2012-12-01' AND localt < '2013-01-01';

create or replace view test_wide_inheritance_2012 as 
          SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201201
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201202
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201203
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201204
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201205
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201206
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201207
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201208
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201209
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201210
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201211
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM public.test_wide_inheritance_201212;
```

If you are following from home, please note that the first table is 45GB, and each of the monthly tables is 3.9GB, each index off of the big table is 2.2GB and each index off the 12 monthly tables is 242MB. I left out the primary key from all these, but please let me know if that is possibly skewing my results.

Next, I needed a way to evaluate performance, this is certainly tricky and depends on the use case, so I came up with some queries that I expect to be representative and parsed `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Essentially I created randomized queries where there were a variable number of days were selected for half of the queries (also random). It also randomly used the view, the large table, or the parent table using inheritance. I did this in `R` using `RPostgreSQL`:

```
wait <- function(wait.time = 5){
        now <- proc.time()[3]
        while(proc.time()[3] < (now + wait.time)) dum <- 0
}
table_choices <- c("public.test_wide_no_inheritance",
                   "public.test_wide_inheritance_2012",
                   "public.test_wide_inheritance")
set.seed(12345)
starts <- sample(1:366,1000,replace=T)
stops <- sample(1:366,1000,replace=T)
entity <- sample(1:200,1000,replace=T)
table <- sample(1:3,1000,replace=T)
st <- data.frame(starts,stops,entity,table)
st_final <- st[stops>starts,]
st_final$start_date <- first_day + st_final$starts
st_final$end_date <- first_day + st_final$stops
st_final$aday <- 0
st_final2 <- st_final
st_final2$end_date  <- st_final2$start_date + 1
st_final2$aday <- 1
st_final <- rbind(st_final,st_final2)
set.seed(12345)
st_final <- st_final[sample(nrow(st_final)),]
query <- list()
dat <- list()
result <- list()
k <- as.vector(0)
for(k in 1:nrow(st_final)){
  wait(5)
  query[[k]] <- paste("explain analyze 
                      select entity,localt, val01, val02, val03 
                      from ",table_choices[st_final$table[k]]," 
                      where entity = ",
                      st_final$entity[k]," and localt >= '",
                      st_final$start_date[k],"' and localt < '",
                      st_final$end_date[k],"' limit 100",sep="")
  dat[[k]] <- fetch(dbSendQuery(con,
                                statement = paste(query[k])),n=-1)
  result[[k]] <- data.frame(table=st_final$table[k],
                            runtime=as.numeric(substr(dat[[k]],
                            regexpr("Total runtime: ",
                            dat[[k]])[1]+15,nchar(dat[[k]])-5)),
                            entity=st_final$entity[k],
                            start=st_final$start_date[k],
                            end=st_final$end_date[k], 
                            diff= as.numeric(st_final$end_date[k]) - 
                              as.numeric(st_final$start_date[k]))
  print(k)
}
results <- do.call("rbind", result)
```

I don't see any significant difference between the view and the inherited tables. Could this be because I'm using constraints on the smaller tables? Does the inherited version scan all the constraints, and so does the view? Should I not use the constraints? I'm not understanding what table inheritance adds other than making your schema more unique to Postgresql.

Here's the plots showing the results:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's some of my settings using Postgres 9.2.3:

```
name                    setting
max_connections             100
shared_buffers          2097152
effective_cache_size    6291456
maintenance_work_mem    1048576
work_mem                 262144
```

Thank you greatly for any input you can provide.

Comment: btw.  Sweet research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view can also be made from the union or inner/outer join  or filter of tables.  Parent tables were meant to make database models more-closely-match the structures that go along with object-oriented programming.